# MYSQL combine two queries to get the functionality

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that retrieves the users that are online, and a users friends. Now I want to know the best way to combine the two so I can get the results of the users friends that are online.

Friends query:

```
 SELECT 
       CASE WHEN userID=$session 
       THEN userID2 
       ELSE userID 
       END AS friendID 
 FROM friends 
 WHERE userID=$id OR userID2=$session
 LIMIT 18
```

users online:

```
SELECT * 
FROM usersActivity 
WHERE setActivity!=3 
AND userID!=$session
```

usersActivity.userID needs to match friendID

Comment: Impossible to do until you indicate how the `friends` and `useractivity` tables are linked.

Comment: usersActivity.userID needs to match friendID

Comment: As a list or a count?  Give me your use case.

Comment: Well, I will actually want to count the number of users online, AND list the users online.

this is to make a list of users online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query should be:

```
SELECT users.name
FROM usersActivity
INNER JOIN friends ON
    (usersActivity.userID = usersActivity.userID AND usersActivity.userID2 = $session) OR
    (usersActivity.userID2 = usersActivity.userID AND usersActivity.userID = $session)
INNER JOIN users ON
    (usersActivity.userID = users.userID) OR
    (usersActivity.userID2 = users.userID)
WHERE usersActivity.setActivity!=3 
    AND usersActivity.userID!=$session
    AND users.userID != $session
GROUP BY users.id
```

You may use `COUNT(user.id)` if you want only count of users. Or select all names (store them for later use in listing) and use only `mysql_num_rows()` for getting actual number of friends online

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what your after:

```
SELECT userID FROM usersActivity 
  WHERE setActivity !=3 
  AND userID IN(
  (SELECT userID FROM friends WHERE userID2=$id)
);
```

This assumes you have double rows for your friend linking table and `$id` is the current logged in user.

```
userID  userID2
1       2
2       1
```

Using subqueries in your where statement should consolidate this.  Not sure if this will be faster or not, depends on how you are doing things so profile it.  You can join on your users table to get the friends name information and what other info you need.

Comment: my setup only has one row for a friendship, not two. Which is where my case clause comes into play in getting the friendID

Comment: Yea you can modify the subquery, this is just an example to get you where you need.  Add your CASE to the where inside the subquery.

Comment: Also, you may want to consider doubling your rows for performance reasons.